# Why does kedusha text differ sometimes?

Tags: tefilla, minhag, words, shemoneh-esrei, prayer-book

In some prayerbooks the Kedusha doesn't start like "Nekadesh et simha..." but like "Nekdisha vonaaricah..."

What's the reason for the difference? Also I can see that among the blessings there are some differences.

Answer (score 1):

Nusach Ashkenaz renders (even in Eretz Yisrael)

> 'נקדש את שמך וכו

and Nusach Edot HaMizrach and Sefard render

> 'נקדישך ונעריצך וכו

I believe the latter is based on the Arizal and kabbalah, but I'm not really an expert in that area.  This is only one of the many differences between Ashkenazi and Sephardi nusachot.

Nusach Sefard (which is the Chassidic nusach) generally uses the Sephardi Kedushah beginning נקדישך but you might find some sects which recite נקדש instead according to the Ashkenazi custom.

This is not the best answer (as I have yet to find why there is a difference of נקדש/נקדישך), but maybe it will provide a bit more information.

Answer (score -2):

"Nekadesh et simha" is the Ashkenaz version 
"Nekdisha vonaaricah..." is the Edot HaMizrach version
maybe you saw Ashkenaz siddur and edot hamizrach siddur

Comment: To OP. Is this answer sufficient? Or, are you also curious about the history behind these versions?

Comment: History would be interesting